# How to get next 9 week numbers from current date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, week-number

If I am giving date as 2015-12-31, it must display as

```
    2015W53, for 2015-12-31, which means Week 53, and next follows as
    2016W1,  Next as
    2016W2,  Next as
    2016W3   Next as...
```

My logic was

```
    DECLARE @WEEK VARCHAR(2), @YEAR VARCHAR(4) 
    SELECT @YEAR = DATEPART(YY,@DATE), @WEEK = CAST(DATEPART(WK,@DATE) AS INT) % 52 ; 
     IF(CAST(DATEPART(WK,@DATE) AS INT) % 52 = 0) 
       SET @WEEK = 52; 
     IF(CAST(DATEPART(WK,@DATE) AS INT) = 53) 
       SET @YEAR = CAST(@YEAR AS INT) + 1; 
     IF (LEN(@WEEK) < 2) 
    BEGIN 
      SET @WEEK = LEFT('0' + @week, 2) 
    END 
    RETURN @YEAR + @WEEK
```

But here **2015W53** is missing and iam getting next 9 weeks,

I just want my last week of the year too..,
Tried many times but could not get.
Any help is very thankful.

Comment: It looks like your code is trying to generate leading zeros, i.e. `2016W01` not `2016W1` as in your spec. (FWIW I think the leading zeros is better!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate as you want. No need to loop either

```
SELECT
    YEAR(DATEADD(week, X.Y, BaseDate)),
    DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATEADD(week, X.Y, BaseDate))
FROM
    (SELECT CAST('20151231' AS date) AS BaseDate) D
    CROSS JOIN
    (
    VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8)
    ) AS X(Y);
```

**Update** SQL Server 2008 added the [ISO_WEEK datepart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) which fixes the week numbering

This almost works because week 2 starts on 03 Jan 2016 according to SQL Server. This is different to ISO [week numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-day_week#Week_numbering).

Comment: Here iam getting output with 1st week missing, 2015W52,2016W02 iam missing 1st.....

Comment: As expected, as per my link

Comment: +1 - Does the same as my solution, but way more elegant :-) Didn't know you could do that!

Comment: @gbn  SELECT DatePart(Week, '20160101') AS Week 
      ,DatePart(Iso_Week, '20160101') AS IsoWeek .
       
Here my output is Week as 1 and Iso_Week as 53, 
i want it in  ISO8601 format, any help please...

Comment: @gbn I don't see anything in that link about skipping week number 1? Or the [ISO week date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) article.

Comment: It's SQL Server numbering. Not ISO. My bad

Comment: @gbn: My solution is the answer that you edited to use a fixed date instead of the current timestamp.

Comment: @Pink: fixed. SQL Server now supports ISO weeks

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: I know. It has the same problem I had before: week 1 was missed. ANyway, fixed now

Comment: @gbn Sorry, I thought you asked what my solution was, but in fact it was the OP asking. Got mixed up :-D

Answer (score 0):

You may not set `@WEEK` as `DATEPART(WK,@DATE) % 52`, as some years have more than 52 weeks! If every year had exactly 52 weeks, things would be easy.

Why don't you just determine the week for the given `@DATE` and then use `DATEADD` to add a week and see what comes out? You do this 9 times and you get what you want.

For example:

```
DECLARE @yearsAndWeeks TABLE (Year INT, Week INT)

DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 0

DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SET @Date = '20151231'

WHILE @i < 9
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @yearsAndWeeks (Year, Week) VALUES (DATEPART(yy, @Date), DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, @Date))
    SET @Date = DATEADD(WK, 1, @Date)
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @yearsAndWeeks
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Date** is the start date from when you want the week data and **@NumberOfWeeks** is the number of subsequent weeks for which you want the data. Please modify these values as required.

```
 --Create the temp table to hold the data
    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Dates') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Dates;

CREATE TABLE #Dates
(   [Year]          INT NOT NULL,
    [WeekNumber]    INT NOT NULL,
    [RequiredWeek]  NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [Date]          DATETIME NOT NULL
);


--DECLARE @Date        Datetime='2016-1-1';   --for testing
--DECLARE @Date        Datetime='2016-12-31'; --for testing
DECLARE @Date          Datetime='2015-12-31';
DECLARE @Days          INT;
DECLARE @NumberOfWeeks INT;
DECLARE @Ctr           INT=0;

SET @NumberOfWeeks=9 

WHILE @Ctr<@NumberOfWeeks
BEGIN
    SET @Days=@Ctr*7

    INSERT INTO #Dates
    SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR,@Date+@Days) AS [Year],
            DATEPART(wk,@Date+@Days) AS [WeekNumber],
            CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,@Date+@Days) AS VARCHAR(10))+'W'+ CAST(DATEPART(wk,@Date+@Days) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [RequiredWeek],
            @Date+@Days AS [Date]
    SET @Ctr=@Ctr+1
END

SELECT * FROM #Dates;
```

OUTPUT:

```
Year    WeekNumber  RequiredWeek    Date
2015    53          2015W53          2015-12-31 00:00:00.000
2016    2           2016W2           2016-01-07 00:00:00.000
2016    3           2016W3           2016-01-14 00:00:00.000
2016    4           2016W4           2016-01-21 00:00:00.000
2016    5           2016W5           2016-01-28 00:00:00.000
2016    6           2016W6           2016-02-04 00:00:00.000
2016    7           2016W7           2016-02-11 00:00:00.000
2016    8           2016W8           2016-02-18 00:00:00.000
2016    9           2016W9           2016-02-25 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: But here ccant i get 2015W53 after that i want 2016w1.., Is that not possible??

Comment: well , as I am adding 7 as the duration you get 2016-Jan-7 which actually falls under week 2 of 2016. Now, the issue is that both 31st of Dec 2015 and Jan 1st of 2016 fall in the same week. If your requirement is fixed (i.e. your start date will always be 31st DEC 2015) then as an exception you can have a condition to just add 1 or 2 days in the first run of the WHILE Loop.

Answer (score 0):

To customize it further to your needs and with the risk of making this solution non generic, here is the code which gives 2016W1 after 2015W53 assuming the starting date is '31st DEC 2015'

```
--Create the temp table
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Dates') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Dates;

CREATE TABLE #Dates
(   [Year]          INT NOT NULL,
    [WeekNumber]    INT NOT NULL,
    [RequiredWeek]  NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [Date]          DATETIME NOT NULL
);


--DECLARE @Date Datetime='2016-1-1';
--DECLARE @Date Datetime='2016-12-31';
DECLARE @Date Datetime='2015-12-31';
DECLARE @Days INT;
DECLARE @NumberOfWeeks INT;
DECLARE @Ctr INT=0;

SET @NumberOfWeeks=9 

WHILE @Ctr<@NumberOfWeeks
BEGIN
    IF (@Date ='2015-12-31' AND @Ctr=1)  -- To handle 1st week of Jan 2016
    SET @Days=@Ctr+1
    else if (@Date ='2015-12-31' AND @Ctr=0) --To Handle last week of Dec 2015
    SET @Days=(@Ctr)*7
    else
    SET @Days=(@Ctr-1)*7   --for rest of the weeks of 2016

    INSERT INTO #Dates
    SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR,@Date+@Days) AS [Year],
            DATEPART(wk,@Date+@Days) AS [WeekNumber],
            CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,@Date+@Days) AS VARCHAR(10))+'W'+ CAST(DATEPART(wk,@Date+@Days) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [RequiredWeek],
            @Date+@Days AS [Date]
    SET @Ctr=@Ctr+1
END

SELECT * FROM #Dates;
```